# Default image not shown in ASP ImageField

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In my asp.net gridview there's an ASP ImageField,When image is not shown or broken I need to show the Default Image, here I use NullImageUrl for this but this won't work.

My Code:

```
<asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="FilePath" ControlStyle-Height="50" ControlStyle-Width="50" HeaderText="Image Preview" NullImageUrl="~/images/Defaultimg.png" />
```

Comment: check the db for image filed is null or empty,if empty then it wont work.

Comment: @KarthikManoharan I need when that file is not a image file then need to show default image here.

Comment: Oh fine,same concept but i used differently i will post the code below if you need you may use it.

Comment: @KarthikManoharan pls post.surely it will help me

Comment: weather r u using this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Gridview Image Tag**

```
 <asp:Image class="fbimgsize" ImageUrl='<%# FormatURL(Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "picture"))) %>'
  runat="server" ID="imgUser" />
```

**C# Code:**

```
  public string FormatURL(string img)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Path.GetExtension(img).Equals(".jpg", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                return img;
            }
            else
            {
                return "images/noimage.jpg";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
           return "images/noimage.jpg";
        }

    }
```

Comment: This can't be do it with ASP Image Field know ?

Comment: why you can use image filed

Answer (score 0):

The solution of @KarthikManoharan does work for local images. However, if you need to keep the ImageFields or need to check remote images, too, you have to add a few lines of javascript to your code. The NullImageUrl property is taken into account only when the corresponding bound datafield is null. It does not check whether or not the image url is valid.

To fix your broken URL's you could do this:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="mySuperGridView">
        <Columns>
            <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="ImageUrl" HeaderText="Image Preview" NullImageUrl="~/images/replacement.jpg" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>    

$(function() {
    $("#mySuperGridView").find("img").error(brokenImageHandler);
});

function brokenImageHandler(image, param1) {
    $(image.target).attr("src", "images/replacement.jpg");
}
```

Keep in mind that this function would replace all broken images in your gridview. If you want your ImageFields considered solely you need to a custom attribute to your ImageFields. This can be done in the RowDataBound event of the gridview.